# Activar un campo disable con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html5, funciones

Estoy programando en PHP y necesito habilitar unos campos de un formulario cuando le de a un botón, para esto he creado una función con JavaScript pero no se habilita nada solo aparece en mi URL: "http://localhost/ecomerce/sistema/nuevafactura.php#" No sé que podría estar mal.
Aquí está el formulario:
La clase es btn_new_cliente
El botón para que al que le tengo que dar es a Nuevo Cliente

```
<h4>Datos del Cliente</h4>
                <a href="#" class="btn-new btn_new_cliente">Nuevo Cliente</a>
            </div>
            <form name="form_new_cliente_venta" id="form_new_cliente_venta" class="datos">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCliente">
                <input type="hidden" name="idCliente" id="idCliente" value="" required>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>DNI</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dni_cliente" id="dni_cliente" class="dni_cliente">
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nom_cliente" id="nom_cliente" disabled required><!--Está desactivado-->
                </div>
                <div class="wd30">
                    <label>Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="number" name="tel_cliente" id="tel_cliente"  disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Dirección</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dir_cliente" id="dir_cliente" class="dir_cliente" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Localidad</label>
                    <input type="text" name="loc_cliente" id="loc_cliente" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>Provincia</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pro_cliente" id="pro_cliente" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div class="wd100">
                    <label>País</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pai_cliente" id="pai_cliente" disabled required>
                </div>
                <div id="div_registro_cliente" class="wd100">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn_save">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Aquí está mi función de JavaScript para quitar el atributo disabled:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.btn_new_cliente').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#nom_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#tel_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#dir_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#loc_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#pro_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');
        $('#pai_cliente').removeAttr('disabled');

        $('#div_registro_cliente').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu problema no se puede reproducir con el código que has suministrado. Funcionar funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/oe4w8sf7/

Comment: Y por qué puede ser que a mi no me funcione?

Comment: No puedo pasarte todo el código por aquí como lo hago @masterguru

Comment: ¿Porqué asignarle la funcionalidad de botón a un elemento `<a>`? Usa otro tipo de elemento más apropiado, como un `<input>` o directamente `<button>`. Saludos

Comment: en el jsfiddle funciona bien, pero como te dicen arriba, estas intentando usar un anchor para recrear el comportamiento de un boton. Deberias usar un boton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314019/anchor-or-button

Comment: Exactamente, como dicen los compañeros, el código funciona correctamente. Y además del comentario sobre el `<a>` y cambiarlo por un `<button>`, quizá te convenga también revisar el tema del teléfono tratado como número. Y también, para simplificar cosas, podrías utilizar clases para todos esos ìnput` bloqueados (por ejemplo añadiendo `class="bloqueo_en_edicion"`) y después utilizarla cuando pulsen el botón, poniendo `$(".bloqueo_en_edicion").removeAttr('disabled')` en lugar de todas esas instrucciones repetidas. Y además así sería más sencillo añadir algún campo en el futuro.